# Termination Requirements for DRAM

Tags: memory, dram

I am curious about how to wire DRAM to an SoC. What is required for optimal usage other than the net itself? I have seen conflicting information on if you should or should not use a termination resistor ([here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203562/how-to-route-a-trace-on-pcb-with-50-ohm-impedance)). There hasn't been much information I could find on connecting DRAM, which makes me think that a direct connection is what most board designers use, as otherwise there would be information on what would be needed to reduce EMI. I'm planning on using Micron MT40A1G8SA-062E for DDR4 RAM and a MIMX8MM6DVTLZAA SoC by NXP.

Comment: DRAM is a broad term, you need to provide which memory interface you wish to terminate. A datasheet or part number would be helpful. Not every SoC can interface to every DRAM (many drams use transceivers)

Comment: @VoltageSpike Hi, currently I'm looking at using MT40A1G8SA-062E by Micron for DDR4.

Comment: And which SoC? Can you edit your question?

Comment: @VoltageSpike Just edited. I'm using a MIMX8MM6DVTLZAA SoC.